# WCF - Instancing mode as Single query

Tags: wcf

When we use Instancing Mode as Single, only single instance will serve to all clients
. now we have a resource which is used by 1 client and some other client also
makes a request for same resource consumed by previous client...

How this scenario can be handelled in WCF ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is dont use Single instance of WCF instead use PEr Session or Per Call but still if you want to use the Single mode then use threading concept to check if the resource is being consumed by some other client, if yes then wait for that thread to get finish and then use resource for the waiting client. Or even if needed you can use a flag to see if that resource being consumed by some other client.